# Yocto nl80211 not found

Tags: yocto

I am new to yocto. I am trying to run the built-in Wi-Fi in Raspberry Pi Zero W using yocto.

I am getting this error when running `iw wlan0`:

`nl80211 not found`

I have included the following packages in my recipe:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libnl iw dnsmasq hostapd avahi-daemon iptables wpa-supplicant connman"`

Comment: Welcome! Did you already take the [tour] and read [ask]? I'm not sure if your question is on-topic here, since yocto is a generic tool and not specific to Raspberry Pi. Maybe [Super User](//superuser.com/) would be better suited for this question. Either way, make sure your question contains enough details, and focus on only one question. Re: "_Where can I find resources to learn yocto?_" -> use any search engine. Asking for references to online material is [off-topic](//raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. NB: as far as I know, yocto is very complex and hard to learn. Good luck.

Comment: By the way, did you see the [Get Started Here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) link on the [Yocto Project](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) website? And the [Yocto Project Documentation](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/) page, with an overview of all documentation?